# Does operating system affect HTML audio formats?

Tags: html, operating-system, html5-audio, playback

I was reading through the [HTML5 Audio Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio), and I wanted to know if different operating systems (linux, mac, android, windows, and etc) affect the audio formats supported in different web browsers. Does different operating systems affect the audio formats of the same browser differently (like what it is actually supported or not)?

Also if above statement is true, can someone guide me on where to find a list of supported devices for audio formats depending on the operating system and the web browsers as well? I was looking for a big list, but this was all I could find [supported list](https://docs.w3cub.com/browser_support_tables/aac).

Comment: Does this and linked information answer your question? [HTML Element Audio: Usage Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#usage_notes)

Comment: It does not. I wanted to see if audio formats are restricted or supported with the combination of web browser + operating system. I am not sure how the Usage Notes will help me.

Comment: Because it contains a [link to exactly the information you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs), on which browsers support which codecs.

Comment: There is no limitation to what a web browser can implement as audio codec. It is mostly licensing issues that prevent a web browser implementer from directly supporting a codec. They thus choose to use external libraries that are often natively available on operating-systems. The operating-system doesn't really care about the codec. It can simplify and speed up its playback by providing "transforms". In all cases, nothing prevents a web browser from just interpreting/decompressing a codec to feed raw audio to the os for playback.

Comment: The web browser doesn't have access to the audio hardware. It must use os APIs that will themselves do syscalls probably on some virtual file that will be opened and written to. It allows to interact with the audio hardware (audio controller) which is probably a PCI device.

Comment: @cSharp Thank you for the comment. I was looking for more of combination of both web browser & operating system compatibilities onaudio codecs; not just web browser compatibility. Only OS this website covers is firefox since it requires operating system or external library.

Comment: @user123 So if I understood correctly, which codec is supported has nothing to do with which OS (Android, IOS, Linux, and etc) I am using the web browser on for playback. Supporting a codec or not is just only dependent on which browser I use. Did I understand correctly? Sorry, english isn't my strong language.

Comment: Yes only dependent on the browser and the work they did or not to implement a codec or not.